# Suppress notifications in top menu about new Likes for Facebook Page admin

Tags: facebook

I have admin rights on three Facebook pages for organizations. However, I really need to stop the many daily notifications appearing in my top menu pulldown telling me when this or that new user has Liked the page or liked this or that image in the page.  These are totally cluttering up my "new items" notices in that menu.

How do I tell it to tell me LESS about those three pages I have admin roles on, up in that top pulldown menu?

In short:  I really want my little "globe" pulldown menu to not have items about the pages that I am ADMIN of.  I want the "globe pulldown menu" to *only* have items about my PERSONAL facebook account.

Comment: Not possible, yet.

Comment: facebooks implied opt in stance strikes again :( I too am desperate for a way to disable this. You can disable email notifications for pages, just not on the notification tab

Comment: just noticed, if i am admin for a page, and that page likes other pages, i get notifications for those pages that i'm not even admin for, nor like on my personal facebook account. super annoying!!!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I've been looking for this more than 15 minutes and I think I can conclude that this is just not possible.

Weird thing is that I own 5 pages myself as well, but only get these notifications from 1 of them. What I have to add, though, is that only that 1 page ever has notifications :)

So I just don't think this is possible. You can maybe try do degrade yourself from Admin to Editor. But probably you will lose the ability to revert this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible go your profile:

Then click to MECHANISM,  SETTING ACCOUNT (top Right)

-------->>>  Now LOOK WELL at your left column menu you will find

--------- NOTIFICATIONS  ----------- click on here

from this menu VISUALIZE the ICON with the FLAG -----> PAGE that you are admin

Click on this and you will see the list of all you page where you are admin so flag or unflag what you need.